# Pushing data to sheet, cell A1 breaks if the cursor is not moved to new cell after sheet creation

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a Chrome extension that uses Google sheet API to push the title of columns to be able to scrape some data. I've noticed that if you create a new sheet and just leave cell A1 in focus, where it says *Type @ to insert* then the text will actually push to the cell, but you can't actually see it unless you highlight the cell and look in the formula bar. The background color is also not shown, but highlighting it shows the color is properly set  in the cell's options (if you start typing to modify the cell's contents, the background becomes visible only during this time, but clicking away changes the cell back to showing the default).

As far as I can tell, the easiest fix for this to prevent it from happening is to just move the highlighted cell in focus to anything else before you connect the sheet to the extension, but I am looking for a way to get around this issue so the user does not have to do that. Is there anything I can send to move the active cell before pushing data? Or any way to modify the code to push the proper data and formatting with no issue, even if A1 is in focus when this is sent?

[Picture to show what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmNvj.jpg)

Here is the function that actually pushes the top row, I assume there isn't anything else that would be needed for this, but please let me know if I'm mistaken.

```js
const sendFirstRowIntoSheet = (sheet) => {
    var pattern = sheet.pattern;
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, (token) => {
        let requests = [{
            updateDimensionProperties: {
                range: {
                    sheetId: sheet.gridId,
                    dimension: "ROWS",
                    startIndex: 0,
                    endIndex: 1
                },
                properties: {
                    pixelSize: 40
                },
                fields: "pixelSize"
            }
        }];
        pattern.forEach((_pattern, index) => {
            if (_pattern.field) {
                requests = [...requests, ...makeCellUpdateRequestObject(sheet.gridId, index, _pattern.field.trim() || "")]
            } else {
                requests = [...requests, ...makeCellUpdateRequestObject(sheet.gridId, index, "")]
            }
        })
        if (requests.length) {
            let parameters = { requests };
            fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheet.sheetId}:batchUpdate`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(parameters)
            })
        }
    })
}
```